# Using super in the sub class to print super class field

Tags: java, super

I ran the following piece of code :

```
class Feline {
    public String type = "f ";

    public Feline() {
        System.out.print("feline ");
    }
}

public class Cougar extends Feline {
    public Cougar() {
        System.out.print("cougar ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Cougar().go();
    }

    void go() {
        type = "c ";
        System.out.print(this.type + super.type);
    }
}
```

And thought the output would be `feline cougar c f` but to my surprise output came out to be `feline cougar c c`.
Can someone please explain.

Answer (score 4):

Superclass is not something a subclass instance *has*, it is something a subclass instance *is*. Your `Cougar` "is a" `Feline`. All members of `Feline` are members of `Cougar` - the same ones, not copies. There is no separate `type` inside the superclass - it is the same `type` member as in the subclass. You can refer to it as `Cougar`'s member or as `Feline`'s member, it's all the same.

Answer (score 2):

Sure - you've only got *one* `type` variable per instance of `Cougar`. It's declared in `Feline` and *inherited* by `Cougar`. Wherever you change the value of that variable, it'll be visible everywhere (for that object).

So if you had another method in `Feline` which printed the current value of `type`, that would print `c` as well (after you'd called `go()`).

Answer (score 1):

You have not coded the field in the subclass:

```
public class Cougar extends Feline {

    public String type = "c ";

    // ...
}
```

Comment: it is not there in the subclass

Comment: Yes - that's why you're not seeing what you expect